# How to download old app using Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading

I want the old version of a particular software from the Google Play Store.

Is there any way to get the old version of that software?

Comment: Not from the Play Store... Have to get them from a 3rd party like APK Mirror or similar site.

Comment: @acejavelin how to get mirror of old apk.

Comment: search google for apk of that app, and, download from links other than google playstore(search with version number if you knows it). We are not responsible for any security issues,if occur.

Comment: Ok got it. But it's unofficial. But no problem.

Comment: There is no official method to get old versions. Remember that using old versions will require you to turn on Unofficial Sources, which can be dangerous... http://www.apkmirror.com/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should check [Aurora Store](https://auroraoss.com) which is an open-source alternative to Google Play Store with privacy and modern design. You can check your software with this program.

Comment: Hello. The question is about downloading an older version of an app from Play Store. Your answer does not address that. By the way, I use Aurora Store and I don't see a way to do what the question asks for.